# How can I pipe this echo at the end of this line instead of at the beginning, in zsh?

Tags: shell, pipe, zsh

Right now I have

`echo 'abcdef' | gzip | wc -c`

What I would like to have is

`$(| gzip | wc -c) ???mystery-pipe-operator??? echo 'abcdef'`

or

`$(gzip | wc -c) <(echo 'abcdef')`

But neither of them work, of course, because I don't know what I'm doing. I want to restructure the echo to the end so that I can edit the string easily when I press up and down to navigate my command-line history.  I'm using zsh.  I know about Ctrl-R to do a reverse incremental search, but it's too much of a hassle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh (and also in bash) you can use a compound command together with process substitution:

```
{ gzip | wc -c; } < <(echo abcdef)
```

or even with a "here string":

```
{ gzip | wc -c; } <<<abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to do:

```
$ s=abcdef
$ echo "$s" | gzip | wc -c
```

and then redefine `s` before repeating the command from your history.  Or use a function:

```
$ foo() { echo "$*" | gzip | wc -c; }
$ foo abcdef
```